# django unescape script tag

Tags: django

```
#base.html
{% autoescape off %} 
//<![CDATA[
{% block inline_script %}{% endblock %}
//]]>
{% endautoescape %}
#some template
{% block inline_script %}
    {% autoescape off %} 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        alert('a');
    </script>
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}
```

result:

> // alert('a'); //]]&gt ;

Why this happens? Hot to fix it?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? What result do you expect, and what do you see instead?

Comment: i expect alert box with message: 'a', istead i see result which i write above. why django 'eat' script and <![CDATA[ when autoescape is off ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem starts here:

```
//<![CDATA[
```

The template generates HTML, and `//` is not a valid HTML comment. Try removing the slashes to see what happens.

Also, consider viewing the HTML source that is produced by this template. You can [validate](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) it to find other errors.

Comment: //<![CDATA[ must in script tag but not outside

Comment: In the code sample you posted, `//<![CDATA[` is not in a script element.